# How to calculate confidence band from mle2 object?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, mle

What is the best way of plotting a confidence band from an `mle2` object in R? The typical `predict(object, interval = 'confidence')` as you can use with `lm` objects doesn't seem to work for `mle2` objects.

I have found the math to calculate confidence bands for linear models (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101318/understanding-shape-and-calculation-of-confidence-bands-in-linear-regression) but I want to plot confidence bands for nonlinear relationships as well.

I would really love an R function to calculate and plot the band no matter what the deterministic function used to create the `mle2` object!

A reproducible example can be found here: [Error: "initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite" not in mle2() but in confint()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27446170/3990506)

Comment: See section 5 of http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/chap7A.pdf for some hints: basically, your choices are the delta method, bootstrapping, or population prediction intervals.  Can you post a reproducible example??

Comment: @BenBolker this was a great read, thank you for sharing. I like your nonchalant title as well :)