# maximum likelihood estimation in R using mle and fitdist

Tags: r, estimation, mle

I cannot manage the problem with the maximum likelihood estimation, could you give me some advise please?
I am trying to fit the parameter of the cumulative distribution function but I have an warning message as follow both with `mle()` and `fitdist()`:

> simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite>

The function is: 1-((1-q)*(1-theta)/q/theta/n)^(1/(n-1)) with the unknown parameter theta

My script for `mle()` is:

```
n<-as.numeric(length(price)) 

pclearing<-function(q,theta) 1-((1-q)*(1-theta)/q/theta/n)^(1/(n-1)) 

dclearing<-function(x,theta) ((1-x)*(1-theta)/x/theta/n)^((1/(n-1))-1)*((1/(n-1))*(((1-theta)/x+(1-x)*(1-theta)/x^2)/theta/n)) 

mledist(price,"clearing",start=list(theta=0.0001))
```

the data is `numeric` named `price`:

```
0.717534108 
0.757705912 
0.598281961 
0.628852956 
0.684588176 
0.6725619 
0.639919151 
0.606366852 
0.658943911 
0.570995452 
0.576200101 
0.558362809 
0.551187468 
0.610156645 
0.620262759 
0.545224861 
0.575795856 
0.629358262 
0.69909045 
1 
0.658110157 
0.587670541 
0.639919151 
0.654850935 
0.602299141 
0.631379485 
0.685447196 
0.771576554 
0.545224861 
0.702880243 
0.655634159 
0.591207681 
0.688731683 
0.603082365 
0.698029308 
0.748863062 
0.665740273 
0.570995452 
0.709499747 
0.535219808 
0.61066195 
0.652602324 
0.729156139 
0.630368873 
0.567205659 
0.641965639 
0.689186458 
0.678120263 
0.577817079 
0.548256695 
0.714754927 
0.535219808 
0.632895402 
0.573774634 
0.59914098 
0.64426478 
0.644012127 
0.535118747 
0.703132895 
0.691258211 
0.716018191 
0.6725619 
0.71104093 
0.665740273 
0.66902476 
0.741359272 
0.719833249 
0.708084891 
0.858767054 
0.555583628 
0.674482062 
0.568468924 
0.535118747 
0.665740273 
0.548256695 
0.728941385 
0.68499242 
0.716801415 
0.568216271 
0.609903992 
0.716270844 
0.717534108 
0.717534108 
0.655634159 
0.615209702 
0.581101566 
0.568468924
```

Comment: [A similar question to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383746/mle-error-in-r-initial-value-in-vmmin-is-not-finite). [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446170/error-initial-value-in-vmmin-is-not-finite-not-in-mle2-but-in-confint?rq=1). [See if they help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757048/initial-value-in-vmmin-is-not-finite-even-when-changing-the-starting-value).

Comment: What is the method you try to use?